# Docker container - Connection Establishment

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm new to docker .

I have a instance named Server 1.

I have a java application deployed in Server 1 , which connects mongo db of Server 2, Elastic search of Server 3.

Installed Docker in Server 1.

I wish to deploy the java application via docker in the server 1.
Written a Dockerfile to deploy the java application in the container, Exposed a port.
Ran that ,application is running successfully.

Checked that application in http://Server-1 IP:exposed-port

But when i try to login , it reports incorrect login.

How to Establish the connection between containers to the Server 2(mongo db ),Server3(Elastic Search )or how to rectify above errors

Tried to assign host's network to the container 
it reports :

```
#docker run -d -p 8116:8116 -m 256m myapp1 --net="host"
421a0c63dd9aea3702eb241721e31c0a0c06357daa555b6155567540896aa014
/usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"--net=host\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\"\n"
```

but if i ran with out network module initially and tried to assign host's network container,
it reports:

```
#docker run -d -p 8116:8116 -m 256m myapp1
421a0c63dd9aea3702eb241721e31c0a0c06357daa555b6155567540896aa014

#docker run -d -p 8116:8116 -m 256m myapp1 --net="host"
0bfe71e4c4cab1391735ecb45fa72a025d9c5ff99fddaf42c0b3a252e1eb826c
/usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint evil_goldwasser (03685ca753672a8cd5fab3e6a35d7569536
46ed9f45e9a927d2ccf1dd532da34): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8116 failed: port is already allocated.
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be enough to export the port e.g., with `-p 8116:8116` for the app/mongo db/Elastic Search to be accessible on that port from external servers. You do not need `--net="host"` for that.

The error with `... \"exec: \\\"--net=host\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\"\n"` is because you pass the `--net="host"` at the wrong place when executing `docker run`. All docker run options should come before the name of the docker image which in your case is myapp1. 
When you add `--net="host"` option after the myapp1 you essentially instruct docker run to start a new container with the myapp1 image and execute the command `--net="host"` which of course does not exists on the $PATH. So that is why you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

You can open needed your port on each container so they can see each othe, or use `--link` https://docs.docker.com/network/links/#the-importance-of-naming for create bridge between containers without opening any ports

Better for your goal is open firewalls on servers and open ports on containers using `-p 5432` or attach port inside container to host machine `-p 5432:5432`

To check which ports open, use `docker ps`

Comment: I need the docker container to point same network of localhost. so it can be communicate with Server 2,Server 3( Mongo db , Elastic Search )